# Mail Kit проверка авторизации если неверный пароль

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

Всем привет если авторизуюсь следующим кодом с верными данными, то все хорошо. Но если указать не верные данные, пишет ошибку
Сервер IMAP неожиданно отключился, в документации написано что должно вызваться при неверных данных исключение AuthenticationException, но у меня вызывается Необработанное исключение типа "MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException" в mscorlib.dll
Дополнительные сведения: The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.(
Сервер IMAP неожиданно отключился. Как сделать проверку если пользователь ввел не правильные данные?

Код

```
 using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput())))
           {
               try
               {
                   client.Connect(server, port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);                   
                   client.Authenticate(user, password);
                   client.Disconnect(true);
               }
               catch (AuthenticationException e)
               {
                   MessegeBox.Show("Не правильный логин или пароль");
               }
           }
```

Comment: У `ImapProtocolException` есть `InnerException`?

Comment: @tym32167 если я делаю так catch(ProtocolException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString()); то получаю ошибку Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: @aepot Ошибка всё таже "Сервер IMAP неожиданно отключился."  Всегда одна и таже ошибка... Хоть в блоке catch пиши попробуйте авторизоваться заново. уже второй день изучаю ответа нету ибо исключение на не верные данные я не получаю.

Comment: У вас создан `ProtocolLogger`, что он выводит в консоль?

Comment: Вообще возможно такая реализация почтового сервера, он не возвращает ошибку, а просто рвет соединение, и под нее просто надо подстроиться.

Comment: @aepot пишет NO Authentication failed. Please verify your account by going to https://e.mail.ru/  но это и так понятно, соединение было же разорвано. Да возможно сайт сам не дает такую ошибку. Вообщем проще в лог писать что не удалось авторизоваться и не искать решения проблемы, так как это похоже бессмысленно.

Comment: Значит ошибка все-таки приходит от сервера, но исключение не выбрасывается. Надо понять, почему.

Comment: [Посмотрите](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573233/mailkit-authenticate-to-imap-fails) почему-то советуют отключить `OAUTH` и `NTLM`. Может еще что интересное найдете в примерах кода.

Comment: @aepot я так делал, результат тот же + на не которые почты без этих параметров нельзя зайти.